# Timezone issue in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, parquet

We are ingesting data in a Hive parquet table from oracle database using an ETL tool. Database is storing time stamps in UTC format however when we see this in Hive table it is showing time stamp values in Eastern (cluster time zone in EST).

Now I understand we could use hive functions to convert this into desired time zone in the select queries executed against the table but my question is can we ask Hive parquet to not convert into cluster time zone while writing data and so display the source value as is ?

The goal is to keep the values same as what we have in source and not allow any implicit conversions. One other way is to treat these time stamp values as strings but we don't want to go with this approach. Appreciate if someone could advise on the right solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Please try this
SET mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Duser.timezone=UTC;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Duser.timezone=UTC; Please follow this linke too https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-do-you-change-the-timezone-for-the-HDP-cluster/m-p/120424

Comment: @Srini tried setting this up at beeline terminal but no use. Could you please advise where and how to set these parameter values?

Comment: usually these two statements need to be executed on the hive interface before insert data into hive external table or internal table.

Comment: @Srini yeah I tried but it's not working