# Hadoop & it's components time zone is by default UTC. Is it possible to change?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Hadoop & it's components uses default time zone as UTC. Is it possible to change this to different timezone?

Eg: in hive & hbase if I want to change is there any configuration & if option is there is it a standard way to to change the timezone?

Now I can able to change it using client side property only.

Thanks

Comment: You can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942298/timezone-issue-in-hive

Comment: AFAIK, Hadoop relies on NTP and the JVM timezone

Comment: hi, is it possible to change it to different time zone in server level.
eg : for hbase,hive etc